Toilet clogging and overflowing every time i try plunging it
My toilet has been clogging for a while now but usually a good plunge takes care of it. I've noticed also that the chain has come unhooked from the flusher handle a few times in the last week and I think it's done that to my granddaughter as well & I've told her to tell me if there's any problems but I think she may have messed with that & maybe other parts in the tank because now the tank is super full of stinky sewage smelling water like my toilet and every time Ive tried to plunge it over the weekend trying to fix it it just overflows. I was trying dish soap and vinegar mixes ect to help unclog it but they didn't help & plunging is still making it overflow. I turned the water off at the line to toilet yesterday so I don't know what could be going on help!!?!?? Please & thank you in advance for any suggestions

Plunging helps push stuff down some, usually enough to get into the bigger pipes.  Needing to plunge often is a sign of a partial clog that needs more work, usually a snake or having to call in a plumber.  Plunging pushes water, the water must go somewhere.  If not down the drain pipe, then the tank is usually the next easy place to go.  The chain might just need to be squeezed a bit to stay on.

Describe what make toilet you have. are you in the US  or another country? It is highly unusual that plunging would force water in the bowl to go back into the tank.  Something more complicated is going on.

Pipe partially blocked by tree roots trapping stuff - get it cleared.

"My toilet has been clogging for a while now but usually a good plunge takes care of it." - You've used up all of your borrowed time, you'll need to call a professional.

In the US. It's an old toilet & I live in a building with 12 units 4 on each floor & I live at the top. I just realized that I've had these worse problems since the maintenance had the drain in the basement worked on which happens every so often & also my bathroom sink is very slow draining but it was fine before

Thank you everyone for your help! I guess I'm just gonna have to call maintenance back and tell them it's kinda an emergency at this point

Yes this is a building maintenance problem.

tell them it's kinda an emergency ... not kinda, it is an emergency

Based on where you live there is absolutely nothing you can do to fix the issue.   You wouldn't even snake this yourself or have a plumber do it.    If there was damage it would be on you.   This is for sure a building maintenance issue and an emergency.   Also something in the basement would not stop a toilet on the 4th floor from working properly - if there is a 1 in 10000000 chance it is your building's main stack is backed up and huge issue
